# How to create link in database

Tags: sql, excel

Trying to create hyperlink

1. field in database:
   select
   CONCAT('<a href="https://srv-jira7:8999/browse/',CONCAT('SPDR','-',iss.Issue_Num),'"','>Go') as Link
   from table
2. The output looks like:
   <a href="https://srv-jira7:8999/browse/"SPDR-9999>Go
3. I am recording it into the table
4. Then I am connecting to the table from EXCEL via SQL data base connection and download table
5. The result looks like: look screenshot[image]

How to do it clickable?

Comment: You are using an HTML anchor tag. I wouldn't know why this is supposed to work in Excel since HTML is made for web browsers and not for Excel. I'd rather try to store the URL directly in the database without any HTML syntax (i.e. "https://example.com") and then see whether Excel parses this as a link.

Comment: Just check it. Not working (